# Reveal CSS animation on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to get bounce.js to show it's animation, when you scroll down the page. As of now, it just plays all the animations right away. Is there some jQuery code, that can do so that it triggers the css animation, when you reach the element? I do not know what is best practice here.

**CSS**

```
.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: my-animation 1s linear both;
}
```

**Bounce.js**

```
var bounce = new Bounce();
bounce.scale({
    from: { x: 0.5, y: 0.5 },
    to: { x: 1, y: 1 }
});
bounce.define("my-animation");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use **Bounce JS**, so I'm going to give you my answer in vanilla **JavaScript** and **CSS**. :)

First off, the **CSS**:

```
.image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
}
.image.animate{ // when the element has class "animate"
    animation: my-animation 1s linear both; // toggle animation
}

@keyframes my-animation{
    0%{
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1); // define how far you want them to move along the x / y axis
    }
}
```

And the **JavaScript**:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e){
    var image = document.querySelector(".image");
    if(this.scrollY == 10){ // if scrolled 10px from the top

        image.classList.add("animate"); // add class "animate"

    } else if(this.scrollY < 10){ // if at top of page

        image.classList.remove("animate"); // remove class "animate"

    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: my-animation is not defined in your css.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 whoops, gimme a sec

Comment: my-animation is defined by bounce.js as seen in my example. Thanks, but isn't there a more clean way to do it with jQuery? I would also like to be free of adding a class to the div.

Comment: @NicolajOlesenReck more than likely. However, **jQuery**, I find, is a very heavy load to take onto your website, and can strain your user experience (especially if they have terrible bandwidth). I guess, as a programmer, my motto would be `don't make your users suffer, simply because you're incapable`. That being said - everybody starts somewhere =) .

Comment: @NicolajOlesenReck also,  I updated my **CSS** so it should work as Bounce would.